# Php str_replace and character °

Tags: php

Im having issues with the character ° , like 30°F. Im doing a string replace but its ignoring only this character:

```
str_replace(array(',', '.', ' ', '´', '°', ':', ';', '!'), "", $name);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Works here](https://eval.in/140081)

Comment: Dump `$name` to check whether its encoded somehow (maybe it's using html entities?)

Comment: OH! i just notice that the character is º with the line below the circle. Thanks i guess is another way to express the same character.

Comment: GRRR it dont take it here but the one that was giving me issues its the same circle but with a little line below it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records. The degree symbol have a variant in some fonts i think on some windows word version that use a Masculine Ordinal Indicator, thats a little line under the degree symbol sort of the one used on Spanish for №, just that is really odd to see it around and in code world is just used without the little line. In my case i was replacing a file name that had it and of course my php didnt replace it and i didnt saw it either even doing a copy paste, i just notice it copying the file name on the link given by I Can Has Cheezburger.

If this is your case, check the file name and replace it with a normal degree symbol or just remove it.